Using SharePoint Secure Service within SharePoint 2013 WOrkflow (on-premise environment)
I have a SharePoint 2019 on-premise environment, with a SharePoint list that users add content to. I want to add a workflow to the list that's triggered each time a new item is added. That workflow calls a OAuth-protected REST API. I need a way to securely store the client_id and client_secret to authenticate to the API. I also need to update the refresh_token each time a new one is returned from the API.
Does anyone know if the SharePoint Secure Store Service can be used for this use case? How can I interact with the Secure Store from within the SharePoint workflow? Tried searching online but all of the examples discuss BCS. Nothing even close to our use case.
